# How do I prevent my Flask App from timing out using Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Creating a flask app where the user can send a excel file and will return a updated excel file.

The problem is sometimes updating the excel file takes to long and heroku will timeout since I haven't returned anything.

Using html forms, post request

I want to send the status code so it would act like as a confirmation and to prevent the timeout.

Then once the file is finished updating, the app downloads the file for the user.
(will be using a job queue)

Since I will need to return 2 things for 1 route, how will it work?

Need to return a status code and the file using send_from_directory()

Answer (score 1):

The 30 seconds timeout on Heroku is fixed, you can not avoid it. Also is not a good idea have a process blocked for so long on a scalable application.

You can use something to execute your slow task on a different process, like python-rq. You have documentation about how to use it on Heroku https://python-rq.org/patterns/

Have in account that Heroku have a ephemeral storage (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), so you can not save a file and expect serve it later. Put your information on redis or a external storage, like S3.